# Identifying Rectangles from a Large Set of Line Segments in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, line-segment

Hello StackOverflow community!

I am currently facing a challenge in detecting rotated rectangles that can be formed from a given set of line segments. With a total of approximately 5000 line segments, the performance becomes a significant concern.

To better illustrate the problem, consider the following example:

```py
segments = [
    [(0, 0), (10, 0)],
    [(10, 0), (10, 10)],
    [(10, 10), (0, 10)],
    [(0, 10), (0, 0)],
]
```

From the above example, these line segments form a rectangle. However, this rectangle is not rotated. But in other cases, the segments might form a rotated rectangle, and I want to be able to detect that.

How can I efficiently determine if a given set of line segments can form a rotated rectangle? Is there any existing algorithm or Python library that can assist with this?

Thank you in advance for any guidance and suggestions!

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


def find_rectangles(segments):
    """
    Finds all rectangles in a list of segments.

    Args:
      segments: A list of segments.

    Returns:
      A list of rectangles.
    """
    rectangles = []
    segments = np.array(segments)
    for i in tqdm(range(len(segments))):
        l1 = segments[i]
        l2 = None
        l3 = None
        l4 = None
        for j in range(len(segments)):
            if are_perpendicular(l1, segments[j]):
                l2 = segments[j]
                break
        if l2 is None:
            continue
        for j in range(len(segments)):
            # l3: Vuong goc voi l2, song song voi l1, ke voi l2
            z =  segments[j]
            if are_parallel(l1, segments[j]) and are_perpendicular(l2, segments[j]):
                l3 = segments[j]
                break
        if l3 is None:
            continue
        for j in range(len(segments)):
            # l4: Vuong goc voi l1, song song voi l2, ke voi l3
            if (
                are_perpendicular(l1, segments[j])
                and are_parallel(l2, segments[j])
                and are_perpendicular(l3, segments[j])
            ):
                l4 = segments[j]
                break
        if l4 is None:
            continue
        lines = np.array([l1, l2, l3, l4])
        points = lines.reshape(-1, 2)
        x = points[:, 0]
        y = points[:, 1]
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)

        rectangles.append(Rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
        print("Found rectangle: ", rectangles[-1])
    return rectangles


def are_parallel(v1, v2):
    """
    Determines if two segments are parallel.

    Args:
      segment1: A segment.
      segment2: A segment.

    Returns:
      True if the segments are parallel, False otherwise.
    """
    slope1 = compute_slope(v1)
    slope2 = compute_slope(v2)
    return slope1 == slope2


def are_adjacent(segment1, segment2):
    """
    Determines if two segments are adjacent.

    Args:
      segment1: A segment.
      segment2: A segment.

    Returns:
      True if the segments are adjacent, False otherwise.
    """
    p1, p2 = segment1
    p3, p4 = segment2
    return (p1 == p3).all() or (p1 == p4).all() or (p2 == p3).all() or (p2 == p4).all()

def compute_slope(seg):
    seg = seg[1] - seg[0]

    angle = np.angle(complex(*(seg)), deg=True)
    return angle


def are_perpendicular(v1, v2):
    """
    Determines if two segments are perpendicular.

    Args:
      segment1: A segment.
      segment2: A segment.

    Returns:
      True if the segments are perpendicular, False otherwise.
    """
    # Không chùng nhau
    # points = np array shape (-1, 2)
    points = np.array([v1[0], v1[1], v2[0], v2[1]])
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = min(points[:, 0]), min(points[:, 1]), max(
        points[:, 0]
    ), max(points[:, 1])
    is_overlap = (xmin == xmax) or (ymin == ymax)
    if is_overlap:
        return False
    # adjacent
    cond2 = are_adjacent(v1, v2)
    if not cond2:
        return False
    # Vuông góc
    s1 = compute_slope(v1) # in degree
    s2 = compute_slope(v2) # in degree
    cond3 = np.abs(s1 - s2) == 90

    return cond3


class Rectangle:
    """
    Represents a rectangle.

    Attributes:
      top_left: The top left corner of the rectangle.
      bottom_right: The bottom right corner of the rectangle.
    """

    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        """
        Initializes a rectangle.

        Args:
          top_left: The top left corner of the rectangle.
          bottom_right: The bottom right corner of the rectangle.
        """
        self.top_left = (xmin, ymin)
        self.bottom_right = (xmax, ymax)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns a string representation of the rectangle.

        Returns:
          A string representation of the rectangle.
        """
        return "Rectangle(top_left=({}, {}), bottom_right=({}, {}))".format(
            self.top_left[0],
            self.top_left[1],
            self.bottom_right[0],
            self.bottom_right[1],
        )


def draw_line(df):
    x = df["x0"].values.tolist() + df["x1"].values.tolist()
    y = df["y0"].values.tolist() + df["y1"].values.tolist()
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)
    w, h = xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin
    mat = np.zeros((ymax - ymin + 1, xmax - xmin + 1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    df[["x0", "x1"]] = df[["x0", "x1"]] - xmin
    df[["y0", "y1"]] = df[["y0", "y1"]] - ymin
    for x0, y0, x1, y1 in tqdm(df[["x0", "y0", "x1", "y1"]].values.tolist()):
        cv2.line(mat, (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (255, 255, 255), 1)
    # cv2.imshow("mat", mat)
    cv2.imwrite("mat.png", mat)
    print('write mat')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    segments = [
                [(0, 0), (10, 0)],
                [(10, 0), (10, 10)],
                [(10, 10), (0, 10)],
                [(0, 10), (0, 0)],
                ]
    # Find all rectangles in the list of segments.
    rectangles = find_rectangles(segments)

    # Print the rectangles.
    rects = []
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        print(rectangle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would group the segments by their vector direction and size. Then in each group you will have segments that are parallel and of the same size. These are candidates for opposing sides of rectangles. When also the connecting sides are perpendicular we have a match.

Here is a way to do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

class Vector(tuple):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector((self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1]))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector((self[0] - other[0], self[1] - other[1]))

    def __mul__(self, other):  # dot product
        return self[0] * other[0] + self[1] * other[1]

def to_vector_pairs(segments):
    # Normalise direction of each segment and turn tuples into Vectors
    return [
        list(map(Vector, sorted(segment)))
        for segment in segments
    ]

def key_by_vector(segments):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for a, b in segments:
        d[b - a].append(a)
    return d

def find_rectangles(segments):
    vectors = key_by_vector(to_vector_pairs(segments))
    for v, offsets in vectors.items():
        if v[0] <= 0 or v[1] < 0:  # only look at vectors in first quarter
            continue
        for a, b in combinations(sorted(offsets), 2):
            side = b - a # third side connecting the two parallel segments
            # check 3rd side is perpendicular and 3rd & 4th are segments
            if v * side == 0 and side in vectors and a in vectors[side] and a + v in vectors[side]:
                yield a, b, b + v, a + v
```

Here is an example use:

```
    segments = [
        [(3, 0), (6, 1)],
        [(6, 1), (10, 1)],
        [(10, 1), (10, 4)],
        [(10, 4), (9, 6)],
        [(9, 6), (7, 8)],
        [(7, 8), (4, 7)],
        [(4, 7), (3, 10)],
        [(3, 10), (0, 9)],
        [(0, 9), (1, 6)],
        [(1, 6), (3, 0)],
        [(6, 1), (6, 3)],
        [(6, 3), (10, 4)],
        [(9, 6), (6, 3)],
        [(6, 3), (4, 5)],
        [(4, 5), (7, 8)],
        [(4, 5), (4, 7)],
        [(4, 7), (1, 6)],
        [(4, 7), (6, 1)],
        [(6, 1), (5, 1)],
        [(5, 1), (5, 3)],
        [(5, 3), (6, 3)]
    ]
    # Find all rectangles in the list of segments.
    rectangles = find_rectangles(segments)
    # Print the rectangles.
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        print(rectangle)
```

Output for this example:

```
((0, 9), (1, 6), (4, 7), (3, 10))
((1, 6), (3, 0), (6, 1), (4, 7))
((4, 5), (6, 3), (9, 6), (7, 8))
((5, 1), (5, 3), (6, 3), (6, 1))
```

Comment: It runs perfectly. But there are some cases where it doesn't produce the correct result. I will update in the comments and really hope for your support.

Answer (score 0):

For every line segment,
translate the left-most endpoint to the origin.
Now the other endpoint is either in quadrant I or IV,
and arctan will give you an angle θ in the range -90° .. 90°.
Index / order by those angles, possibly using an
[RDBMS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Pick a theta_tolerance of a couple degrees or, ideally, zero.

Now iterate through all segments, ordered by angle.
Upon encountering a new θ, grab all subsequent segments
within tolerance of it.
Now generate angles θ ± 90°,
mapping them back to quandrants I & IV.
Grab all segments that match *those* angles.
See if the segments intersect, such that a rectangle may be formed,
and output any discovered rectangles.
Notice that a batch of similar θ's must include a
pair of parallel segments, and likewise for the batch of ± 90° segments.
(IDK, your problem specification was a bit vague on the intersection detail.
Perhaps the requirement is that an (x, y) of segment1
must exactly match an (x, y) of segment2,
in which case your problem is significantly easier.)

Having identified a rectangle,
mark its four segments as "done"
so you don't double count it
by the time you've moved through another 90°.